# SearchBar in uitableview Not working

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

i have created a custom UITableviewCell with Three labels and passed value to each label . It is working fine till now.Now i want to add searchbar in my app to search through all labels. Here is my code..

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
  productArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//Creating a temparay objects of Person
PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Adeem";
personObj.lastName = @"Basraa";
personObj.phoneNumber = @"123456789";

[productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];

PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Ijaz";
personObj.lastName = @"Ahmed";
personObj.phoneNumber = @"987654321";

[productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];

PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Waqas";
personObj.lastName = @"Noor";
personObj.phoneNumber = @"45656789";
    [productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];

   searchData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[searchData addObjectsFromArray:productArray];

dataTable.delegate=self;
dataTable.dataSource=self;
[dataTable reloadData];





   -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
if ((bar.text !=nil)&&(![searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""])&&(bar.text.length>=3)) {

    searchText=bar.text;
    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSString *stemp in productArray ) {

        NSRange titleResult=[stemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResult.length>0) {
            [array addObject:stemp];
        }

    }
    [bar setShowsCancelButton:YES];

    [self.searchData removeAllObjects];
    [self.searchData addObjectsFromArray:array];
    [self.dataTable reloadData];
    [array  release];


}else {
    [searchData removeAllObjects];
    [searchData addObjectsFromArray:productArray];
    [self.dataTable reloadData];

}
```

problem is when i start typing in searchbar , app crashes. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might help you. 
 In .h file declare
`NSMutableArray *array;`

in .m file write following

`- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{`
`[copyListOfItems removeAllObjects];`
`if([searchText length] &gt; 3) {`

`self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;`
`[self searchTableView];`
`}`
`else {`

`self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;`
`}`
`}`

`- (void) searchTableView {`

`array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`
`NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;`

`for (NSString *sTemp in productArray)`
`{`
`NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];`

`if (titleResultsRange.length &gt; 0)`
`[array addObject:sTemp];`
`}`

`[self.tableView reloadData];`
`}`

I apologize for any mistakes in it.